# Передача данных на сервер из стороннего приложения

Tags: javascript, http, websocket, клиент-сервер

у меня **есть стороннее приложение, выводящее каждые несолько мс данные в json файл без перезаписи.** Так вот мне **нужно как-то подбирать эти данные и отправлять на сервер.** Первое, что пришло в голову - веб сокеты. Т.е. организовать клиент на JS, который постоянно проверял бы этот файл и отправлял данные на сервер, если есть изменения. Однако есть опасения, что из-за той частоты, с которой файл обновляется, ws-клиент просто-напросто может не успевать читать этот файл, из-за чего возможны запинки. Думал ещё и над тем, что б после каждой прочитанной строки ws-клиент отправлял что-то вроде ответа в другой файл о том, что данные приняты. Но не уверен что это решит проблему. Так вот, на сколько вообще жизнеспособно такое решение? Есть какое-то другое решение?

Comment: Проверять на наличие изменений раз минут например ?

Comment: @dresser да, но данные в реальном времени передавать надо. Я просто не знаю, имеет ли вообще смысл через такие костыли это реализовывать, хотя других вариантов тоже нет.

Comment: в любом случае вам наверное лучше попробовать сделать так-как вы задумали, а по ходу дела возникнут уже реальные проблемы и с ними уже можно как-то разбиратся.